# How can I export individual layers in illustrator to pngs?

Tags: vector, adobe, png, adobe-illustrator

I have an Illustrator file that has lots of different vectors on various layers that all need to come together to make a webpage and I'd like to batch-export those into individual component pngs or image files.  I'm not very familiar with Adobe Illustrator. Can someone explain to me how I can export all of those into individual pngs?

Thanks in advance for any help/insights!  I fear I'm using the wrong terminology since I can't seem to find an answer anywhere online.... so any tips would be greatly appreciated :)

I guess I see how that could work for individual pieces... Is there anyway to break the entire artboard out into its individual components though? like a Batch item export? –

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Adobe Illustrator

Answer (score 0):

So can illustrator export the individual layers of an artboard out as their own images?  No, illustrator does not have this function.

However, we are not the first people looking to do this and illustrator is scriptable.  Have a look at [this](http://www.arcticmill.com/2012/08/export-layers-as-png-files-from-illustrator-in-multiple-resolutions.html). Hope that helps a bit more haha

Comment: I guess I see how that could work for individual pieces... Is there anyway to break the entire artboard out into its individual components though? like a Batch item export?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're looking for. My mistake, I will update the answer accordingly and that makes it a much more interesting question haha, at first I thought you were talking about web templating